# d3.jsのグラフの直線を曲線にしたい

Tags: javascript, d3.js

cola.jsを使用して[サンプルプログラム](http://marvl.infotech.monash.edu/webcola/examples/pageBoundsConstraints.html)のようなグラフレイアウトを作っています。
このリンクの直線を曲線に変更することはできますか？d3.jsの[こちらの例](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/5141528)のように
曲線にしてみたいのですが、どの部分で曲線か直線かを指定しているのかよくわかりません。

現在は以下のようにリンクの座標を定義しています。

```
link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
.attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
.attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
.attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
```

これを上記の例にならって、以下のように定義しても、リンクが消えてしまい、
表示されません。どうしたら良いのでしょうか？

```
link.attr("d", function(d) {
    var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
        dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
        dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    return "M" + 
        d.source.x + "," + 
        d.source.y + "A" + 
        dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + 
        d.target.x + "," + 
        d.target.y;
});
```

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 2):

現在の例は、変数`link`が`line`要素になっているとおもいますが、曲線の場合は`path`要素にする必要があります。

たとえば、次のように変数`link`が`path`要素として作成されているか確認してください。

```
var link = svg.append('path');
```

```js
const data = [{
  source: {
    x: 10, y: 10
  },
  target: {
    x: 50, y: 50
  }
}]

const svg = d3.select('svg')

const link = svg.append('path')
  .data(data)
  .attr('fill', 'transparent')
  .attr('stroke', '#000')
  .attr("d", function(d) {
    var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
        dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
        dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    return "M" + 
        d.source.x + "," + 
        d.source.y + "A" + 
        dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + 
        d.target.x + "," + 
        d.target.y;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg />
```